# How to get an average from matrix[array]

Tags: ruby, matrix, average, ruby-1.8.7

(Before start, I am using Ruby 1.8.7, so I won't be able to use fancy stuff.)

As title says, I want to calculate the average of column or row.
But, I can't even find the way to traverse/iterate Matrix form of array from online.

Let's say you have this

```
require 'mathn'

m = Matrix[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
```

Somehow the way I iterate a simple 3x3 array doesn't work with Matrix form of array (Or may be just my code is weird)..What is the proper way to do this? Also, is there a syntax that calculate row and column average of matrix??

Comment: [`Matrix`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.8.7/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) has `rows`, `columns`, `row_size`, `column_size`, `[i,j]`, ... methods (even in 1.8.7), that should be enough to compute your averages. Can you show us what you've tried? Is the problem just that you end up doing integer division?

Comment: http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.8.7/ . It's all there.

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to calculate the average of a specific row or column within a given matrix:

```
require 'matrix'

m = Matrix[
            [1, 2, 3],
            [4, 5, 6],
            [7, 8, 9]
          ]

def vector_average(matrix, vector_type, vector_index)
  vector = matrix.send(vector_type, vector_index)
  vector.inject(:+) / vector.size.to_f
end

# Average of first row
vector_average(m, :row, 0)
# => 2.0

# Average of second column
vector_average(m, :column, 1)
# => 5.0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: You could also write `vector.inject(:+).fdiv(vector.size)` or (Ruby v2.4+) `vector.sum.fdiv(vector.size)`. This uses [Integer#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Integer.html#method-i-fdiv), [Float#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Float.html#method-i-fdiv) or [Numeric#fdiv](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Numeric.html#method-i-fdiv), depending on the receiver's class (but I haven't checked to see when these methods were introduced).

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to compute all row averages and/or all column averages you could do the following.

```
require 'matrix'

def row_averages(m)
  (m * Vector[*[1.0/m.column_size]*m.column_size]).to_a
end

def col_averages(m)
  row_averages(m.transpose)
end
```

For example,

```
m = Matrix[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

row_averages(m)
  #=> [2.0, 5.0, 8.0]
col_averages(m)
  #=> [3.9999999999999996, 5.0, 6.0]
```

See [Matrix](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) and [Vector](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html).